# Shiny bookmark - unable to restore some of user's selections

Tags: r, shiny, bookmarks

I have just started include bookmark functionality to my app. My app have a few selection inputs which do not seem to be restored and I couldnt figure out the problems.

The app has 2 key inputs:

- The radio button on the sidebar
- The date/number ranges

At the current state, the app cant seem to restore the radio button (if I switch to duration, it just doesnt work)

The simplify code is below:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(shinydashboard)
library(zoo)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(nycflights13)

flight.dt <- flights %>% mutate(flight.date =ymd(substr(time_hour,1,10)),duration=round(air_time,-2))

### --------Analyse module ---------------------------
plotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("groupmenu")),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

plotServer <- function(id,method,carr) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      filtered.data <- reactive(flight.dt %>% filter(carrier == carr))
      
      output$groupmenu <- renderUI({
        getselection <- if (method() != "duration") c("Year Quarter"="yearqtr") else c("Duration"="dur.grp")
        rng.min <- switch (method(),
                           "date" = min(filtered.data()$flight.date),
                           "duration" = max(0,min(filtered.data()$duration,na.rm = TRUE)))
        rng.max <- switch(method(),
                          "date" = max(filtered.data()$flight.date),
                          "duration" = max(0,max(filtered.data()$duration,na.rm = TRUE)))
        ns <- session$ns
        tagList(
          fluidRow(
            column(2,selectInput(ns("group"), "Group by:",choices =as.list(getselection))),
            conditionalPanel("input.method == 'date'",
              dateRangeInput(ns("daterange"),"Date range:",start  = rng.min,end = rng.max,format = "dd/mm/yyyy",  separator = " - ")),
            conditionalPanel("input.method == 'duration'",
            numericRangeInput(ns("durrange"), label = "Duration range:",value = c(rng.min,rng.max)))
          )  
        )
      })
      
      dt <- reactiveVal(NULL)
      
      observeEvent(input$group,{
        tmp <- filtered.data() %>% mutate(sel.method = switch(method(),"date" = flight.date,"duration" = duration))
        if (input$group == "yearqtr") {
          tmp$key <- paste0(year(tmp$sel.method),"-Q",quarter(tmp$sel.method))
        } else if (input$group == "dur.grp") {
          tmp$key <- tmp$duration
        }
        dt(tmp)
      })
      
      dt.sum <- reactive({
        req(dt())
        setDT(dt())
        if (method() == "date") { 
          tmp <- dt()[sel.method >= input$daterange[1] & sel.method <= input$daterange[2]]
        } else if (method() == "duration") {
          tmp <- dt()[key >= input$durrange[1] & key <= input$durrange[2]]
        } 
        
        tmp %>% group_by(key) %>% dplyr::summarise(count=n())
      })  
      
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        dt.sum() %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.character(key), y = count)) + geom_col() 
      })  
    }  
  )    
}

### UI part -----------------------
header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Analysis')

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  radioButtons("method", "Select method:",c("Date" = "date","Duration" = "duration"),selected = "date"),
  bookmarkButton()
)

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput('tablist'))

ui <- function(request) {
  dashboardPage(title="Analysis", header,sidebar,body)
}

### Server part ----------------------------
server = function(input, output) { 
  method <- reactive(input$method)
  
  carr <- reactive(unique(flight.dt$carrier)[1:3])
  
  ntabs <- reactive(length(carr()))
  
  observeEvent(ntabs(),{
    lapply(1:ntabs(), function (i) plotServer(paste0("count",i),method,carr()[i]))
  })  
  
  output$tablist = renderUI({
    addtabs <- lapply(1:ntabs(),function (i) {
      tabPanel(carr()[i],plotUI(paste0("count",i)))
    })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, addtabs)
  })
}

### Running part ----------------------------
enableBookmarking("server")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ui elements you want restored within ui function. See simplified example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

### UI part -----------------------
ui <- function(request) {
  header <- dashboardHeader(title = 'Analysis')
  
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    radioButtons("method", "Select method:",c("Date" = "date","Duration" = "duration"),selected = "date"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
  
  body <- dashboardBody("BODY")
  
  dashboardPage(title="Analysis", header,sidebar,body)
}

### Server part ----------------------------
server = function(input, output) { 

}

### Running part ----------------------------
enableBookmarking("server")
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. Silly me. I thought since the header/sidebar/body variables are inside the ui function anyway, that shouldnt affect the bookmarking functionality